# Mongodb, Replace if exist, otherwise create new docs,

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any built in function in mongodb which accepts an array as input, add each as item as a document, if the document already exist, based on unique indexes (see below), then the document is replaced

In my schema I got these indexes which defines the what `calculation` is unique

```
calculationSchema.index(

      { insId: 1, year: 1, month: 1, day: 1 },
      { unique: true }
    );
```

Create function

```
export const createCalculations = async (calculations: ICalculation[]) => {
  try {
    const createdCalculations = await mongoose
      .model("calculation")
      .create(calculations); // Replace if it exist based on indexs above, otherwise create it
    return Promise.resolve(createdCalculations);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it's called replaceOne with upsert.

Comment: But thats only for a single document. I have an array with thousands of documents.

Comment: Okay, so you need to edit the question to include all relevant information?

Comment: Yeha it was a bit unclear. Updated.

Comment: You could use bulk write with upsert.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875056/2282634