# Mongoose updateMany with different values by unique id like email without loop

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose updateMany with different values by unique id like email
Old BD Data:

```
usersCollection = [  
    { _id: 1, email: "one@gmail.com", name: "one" },  
    { _id: 2, email: "two@gmail.com", name: "two" },  
    { _id: 3, email: "three@gmail.com", name: "three" }  
];
```

Coming Data:

```
users = [  
    { email: "one@gmail.com", name: "oneeee" },  
    { email: "two@gmail.com", name: "twoooo" },  
    { email: "three@gmail.com", name: "three" },  
    { email: "three@gmail.com", name: "four" }  
];
```

What I'm expecting to to have after insert
New DB Data:

```
users = [  
    { _id: 1, email: "one@gmail.com", name: "oneeee" },  
    { _id: 2, email: "two@gmail.com", name: "twoooo" },  
    { _id: 3, email: "three@gmail.com", name: "three" },  
    { _id: 4, email: "three@gmail.com", name: "four" },  
]
```

I'm Thinking like:

```
const newUsers = [  
    { email: "one@gmail.com", name: "oneeee" },  
    { email: "two@gmail.com", name: "twoooo" },  
    { email: "three@gmail.com", name: "three" },  
    { email: "three@gmail.com", name: "four" },  
];
const someQuery = {};
User.updateMany(someQuery, newUsers, {upsert: true}, (userErr, userDoc) => {  
    return userDoc;  
});
```

Comment: How do identify when to insert vs when to update?  In your example, `one@gmail.com` is updated with the new name, but `three@gmail.com` in inserted with the new name "four" while leaving the old name "three"

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array.map to shape each input for use with a bulk write.

The behavior you are describing seems to be using the `email` field to identify each document.

You didn't indicate what should happen with other fields in the documents.  If you want to leave other fields alone, use `$set` to remove any fields not mentioned in the incoming data, use `$replace`.

In the shell this looks like:

```
PRIMARY> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "email" : "one@gmail.com", "name" : "one" }
{ "_id" : 2, "email" : "two@gmail.com", "name" : "two" }
{ "_id" : 3, "email" : "three@gmail.com", "name" : "three" }

PRIMARY> let users = [     
  { email: "one@gmail.com", name: "oneeee" },       
  { email: "two@gmail.com", name: "twoooo" },       
  { email: "three@gmail.com", name: "three" },       
  { email: "four@gmail.com", name: "four" }   
]

PRIMARY> let bulkUpdate = db.users.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

PRIMARY> users.forEach(u => bulkUpdate.find({email:u.email}).upsert().update({$set:u}))

PRIMARY> bulkUpdate.execute()
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nMatched" : 3,
    "nModified" : 2,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [
        {
            "index" : 3,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e79ff28ee536df4c4a88e")
        }
    ]
})

PRIMARY> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "email" : "one@gmail.com", "name" : "oneeee" }
{ "_id" : 2, "email" : "two@gmail.com", "name" : "twoooo" }
{ "_id" : 3, "email" : "three@gmail.com", "name" : "three" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e79ff28ee536df4c4a88e"), "email" : "four@gmail.com", "name" : "four" }
```

Take a look at [Model.bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) for an example of how to do this in mongoose.

Comment: I can simply add updateOne in loop with upsert but don't wanna use the server to engage cz there will be millions of data per query.